# Why does this gives me the value exceeding the termination condition in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```js
for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
  setTimeout( function timer(){
    console.log( i );
  }, i*1000 );
}
```

Even if the function passed to setTimeout as an argument doesn't create a new scope, being an entry controlled loop, why does the above code output to 6 & **not 5** for each iteration ?

Comment: Because `i` is incremented in the last iteration of for loop.

Comment: Because the "i++" incrementation is executed

Comment: because `i` is later evaluated, then the timeout is called.

Comment: But isn't 'for' an entry controlled loop which shouldn't bring the flow of control into the iteration for terminating condition?

Comment: `i` is incremented (becoming `6`) **before** the `i <= 5` check is done, which is why that check fails and the loop is exited.

Comment: Aha... Thanks @torazaburo